# Dual of the direct sum $U\oplus U'$

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let $U$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $W=U\oplus U'$. Halmos asserts(in his FDVSs book) that the correspondence $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$ is an isomorphism between $W$ and $W'$.

I'm not sure I understood his notation correctly. Since in the finite dimensional case he does use $x$ in place of the element of $U''$ which is related to it by reflexivity I'm thinking he means that $(y,x)$ is $g \in W' ~|~  g(X,Y) = y(X)+x(Y)$. This indeed makes it an isomorphism. Is there another possible interpretation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that every finite dimensional $k$-vector space $X$ is canonically isomorphic to its double dual $X''$.

Moreover, if you have a direct sum of two vector spaces $V=A\oplus B$, you can consider $\{a_i\}_i$ a basis of $A$, $\{b_j\}_j$ a basis of $B$, so that $\{a_i\}_i \cup \{b_j\}_j$ is a basis of $V$. Since linear maps can be defined simply on bases, you have the canonical isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Hom}(A \oplus B,k) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(A,k) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(B,k)$$
acting as $f \mapsto (f|_A, f|_B)$, with inverse $(g,h) \mapsto ((a,b) \mapsto g(a)+h(b))$.

So
$$W' = \operatorname{Hom}(U \oplus U',k) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(U,k) \oplus \operatorname{Hom}(U',k) = U' \oplus U'' \cong U'\oplus U$$
this means that $W'$ is canonically isomorphic to $W$ simply by swapping the two coordinates (i.e. precisely $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$).

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer without using functors? I'm not familir with category theory yet and it hasn't been used by Halmos so far. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you know the notation $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ as the vector space of linear transformation between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you. I was having some problems since Halmos usually uses $A'$ for $Hom(A,k)$ if $k$ is implicit.